# Rewrite: Apache to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

could someone tell me, how to convert the following rules for nginx?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite